# Differentiating the $L_1$-norm

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have been reading somewhere that gradient descent cannot be used for a non-differentiable function. And apparently the $L_1$-norm is not differentiable at every point, specifically at the point zero. As a beginner to optimization, the reason for both these is confusing to me...

For example, let's say I have a data pair $(x, y)$, and a function $f(x)$ which depends on some parameters $m$. I want to learn the parameters which minimize a cost function.

Now let's say that this cost function $C$ is the sum of the absolute differences between each $y$ and each $f(x)$. So, $C = \sum{[f(x) - y]}$ over all data pairs. This is the same as the $L_1$-norm.

Suppose that this is linear regression, so $f(x) = ax$. Differentiating the cost function, we get $\frac{dC}{dm}=\sum{a}$, because $\frac{df(x)}{dm} = a$.

Based on this all being correct....why is this cost function not differentiable at all points, given that apparently the derivative is simply $a$ at all points?

Comment: $\frac{df}{dx}$ is $a$, but $\frac{d}{dx} |f(x)-y|$ is not $a$. In particular this derivative does not exist when $f(x)=y$ (unless $a=0$, of course).

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand why $\frac{d}{dx}|ax-y|$ is not $a$. $|ax-y|$ is equivalent to $\sum_i (a_i x_i - y_i)$.

Comment: notice that $C(m) = \sum_{i} | f(x_i; m) - y_i |$. Now, $C$ is not differentiable at such parameter $m$ where $f(x_i; m) = y_i$ for some $i$ and $f(x_i; \cdot) \ne y_i$ in a deleted neighborhood of $m$ (that is without $m$). There obviously more cases.

Comment: @Karnivaurus You're using the phrase "$L^1$ norm" here, so I assume you mean the absolute values of the differences, not the actual differences themselves. Without the absolute values, you're not writing down a norm at all.

Answer (score 1):

L1 optimization is a huge field with both direct methods (simplex, interior point) and iterative methods.  I have used iteratively reweighted least squares (IRLS) with conjugate gradient and approximate inner iterations.  In practice, the fact that the absolute value is not differentiable at the origin is not really a problem.  E.g., minimizing over x, $\sum |x - x_i|$ just says x is the median of the $x_i$ since the derivatives are all +/- 1 (assuming x is not one of the $x_i$).  Here is a reference.  Robust methods in inverse theory JA Scales, A Gersztenkorn Inverse problems 4 (4), 1071.  There is a pdf on Google Scholar.  The algorithm described can be used for any Lp norm optimization for p not less than 1.  They are all nonlinear except for $p=2$ but we found that using the approximate inner iterations made the L1 problem almost as fast as the least squares problem.  **Added:**  an interesting historical note is that L1 optimization was invented by Boscovich **before** Gauss invented least squares.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into the proximal descent algorithms. This allows you to compute the gradient update where some of the regularization terms are non-differentiable.